# Отсутствует папка src в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При создании нового проекта в Intellij IDEA файлы в папке .idea стали подчеркиваться зеленым и пропала папка src. Прикладываю картинку, как все это выглядит в структуре проекта. Помогите кто-нибудь, пожалуйста...Я совсем новичок в программировании и с идеей толком не разобралась ещё:(
Думала, что смогу как-нибудь сама поправить структуру, но как не старалась, ничего не вышло, гугл тоже ответов, почему такая фигня началась и как её исправить, не дал. До этого пустой проект создавался нормально, с папкой src, зеленым ничего не подсвечивалось. Проблема началась, когда удалила плагин джавараш и восстановила старый проект из корзины (потом его всё-таки удалила[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: sdk поставила, но папка src не появляется, как её вернуть не знаю (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что зеленым подсвечивается - это ничего страшного, просто где-то наверное оставили галочку `Create Git repository` при создании проекта.

Насчет отсутствия src - можете создать вручную.
А если хотите, чтобы сразу было при создании проекта, выбирайте не `Empty Project`, а `New Project` опцию.

Это на версии **Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.4**.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Теперь разобралась!

Comment: @Dana пожалуйста, пометьте ответ галочкой, если больше нет вопросов)